# Decoding Special Characters in Python from subproccess.run

Tags: python, encoding, cmd, active-directory, subprocess

Python version: 3.7
OS: Server 2008 r2 - functioning as AD server

I am running a python script to do a **dsquery** lookup via cmd using the following code:

```
import subprocess
instruction = "dsquery user domainroot -samid 18129"
output = subprocess.run(instruction, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Then to get my results I run:

```
result = str(output.stdout.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

or

```
result = str(output.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

I've tried both. Generally speaking this works beautifully and I have no issue. I usually get a result looking like

```
"CN=Joe Soap,OU=Students,dc=khs,dc=edu"
```

But in the few cases in my network where users have unusual characters in their name like **é** or **ë**, I'm running into errors. Assuming the name Joé Soap

When decoding with UTF-8 I get

```
"CN=Jo\x82 Soap,OU=Students,dc=khs,dc=edu"
```

And with ISO-8859-1 I get

```
"CN=Jo? Soap,OU=Students,dc=khs,dc=edu"
```

Finally if I run the cmd command directly I get the correct response:

```
"CN=Joé Soap,OU=Students,dc=khs,dc=edu"
```

What am I missing here? is there a particular encoding I should use other than the two mentioned above, (I've tried out several others without success) or am I missing something in the process here?

Comment: 0x82 is the codepoint of `LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE` in codepage 437, the traditional English DOS codepage. Do you have different output for the same SAMID?

Comment: @lit No - if I repeat the command directly into cmd I get the expected result: `"CN=Joé Soap,OU=Students,dc=khs,dc=edu"`

Comment: The question says that, "I usually get a result looking like..." Does `Joe` and `Joé` appear for the same SAMID?

Comment: No, the SAMID refers to a specific user DN, which in this case contains `Joé`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by @lit and @vencaslac I've figured out the answer:

```
result = str(output.stdout.decode('CP437'))
```

CP437 is the encoding used by cmd and when applied to my script it successfully returns the **é** or whichever

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a workaround i think but why not use Popen instead of run?

```
def start_process(command=''):
     return subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, creationflags = 0x08000000)

command = start_process('string that you would normally put in cmd window')

result_string = str(command.communicate()[0])
```

it's a little more long winded but in the end it may be easier to use

Comment: This method works in terms of replicating my results. I still get the `Jo?` or `Jo\x82` outlined above

Comment: it's possible that you'll need to do a little more digging, i see what you mean better now, check out these encoding docs `https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html`